# jquery Mobile scrolling and active state

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a set of divs that can be scrolled through on my jquery mobile page. Each div has an active class in CSS so they change color when they are tapped. For some reason when I try to scroll through my list the items turn active because I am 'clicking' them.

That isn't too serious and it looks fine, but there's also another glitch. If the page is intertial scrolling, so I just flicked it and it hasn't stopped moving, a tap on the screen will activate the div I pressed when I first scrolled it.

Any idea what is causing this/how to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

HTML:

```
<div id='someID'>
    <someElement />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#someID').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); //stops default behaviour
    //check to make active/inactive
    if( $('#someID').hasClass('active') ){
        $('#someID').removeClass('active');

        //do what needs to be done when it becomes activated
    } else {
        $('#someID').addClass('active');
        //do what needs to be done when disabled
    }

    //do whatever you always want to here

});
```

Note: whatever requires the click event to work will have to be re-enabled afterwards, though if you use a link/button/etc. within the `div` that has a click event, it'll still function.

Comment: I still want them to go active, just not when they are scrolling

Comment: "active" by using a class? because that's a simple matter of adding a class using .addClass('name')

Comment: I have appended the answer based on the usage of classes, if you use something else feel free to ask, or modify